# Lightning datatable Inline Edit

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, lightning-datatable

Need support on Lightning datatable Inline editing.
When we do inline edit on a cell and edit it, without clicking anywhere else on the window if we click on another cell to edit, the cell takes the value from the previous edited cell.

I tried to get the event oncellClick/Change and tried to delete the value but its not working.

[image]

Comment: Hello, Do you have standard implementation? I'm not able to reproduce this here "Data Table with Inline Edit" https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example

Comment: No this is custom component which is using standard lightning datatable. Do not click anywhere else on table, only on pencil icon. It will not reflect for first 2-3 line items. After that it will start replicating

Comment: Pavlo, you are correct. This behavior is not replicating on standard implementation. If i am embedding the datatable in LWC then i am seeing it.

Comment: Could you please provide a code of your component

Comment: @PavloM Thanks for getting back. I connected with Salesforce Support. This is known issue on LWC. Release patch is expected in Feb
https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000000zGkvQAE